# How do I call a module from my userform in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have trying to call a module by assigning my sub name however it does not work

I tried by

```
Private Sub Filtert04_click()
Call filter 'the sub name
End Sub
```

It would be great if someone could help thx

Comment: `ModuleName.NonPrivateSubName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Sub in the module is defined as `Public`

```
Public Sub DoIt()
  MsgBox "Hi"
End Sub
```

and then from your userform, you can call it like this:

```
Private Sub Filtert04_click()
  DoIt
End Sub
```

Comment: DUDE you are amazing thank you this solved my issue :)